# Neo4j creating duplicate relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am very very new to stack overflow and I am trying to upload a csv file for further querying, however, I noticed the file creates duplicates for the relationships, this is the code I have so far, I have read documentation but can't seem to find the solution for duplicate relationships. Please help.

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///senti.csv" AS csvline
CREATE (:User {username: csvline.username})
CREATE (:Tweet {tweet_id: csvline.tweet_id, text: csvline.text, date_time: csvline.date_time})
CREATE (:Location {place: csvline.location})
CREATE (:Candidate {name: csvline.candidate})
CREATE (:Sentiment {sentiment_polarity: csvline.sentiment});

CREATE INDEX FOR (u:User) ON (u.username);
CREATE INDEX FOR (t:Tweet) ON (t.tweet_id);
CREATE INDEX FOR (l:Location) ON (l.place);

:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///senti.csv" AS csvline
MATCH (u:User {username: csvline.username})
MATCH (t:Tweet {tweet_id: csvline.tweet_id})
MERGE (u)-[:POSTS]->(t);
MERGE (u)-[:BASED_ON]-> (l)
```

Comment: Pls give us a copy of your csv file. Thanks

Comment: The semicolon after `(u)-[:POSTS]->(t);` ends that statement. The next statement would create a single BASED_ON relationship between two nodes with no labels. Do you get the result you expect if you add a second LOAD CSV statement and match the u and l nodes before creating the BASED_ON relationship?

Comment: Try adding r1 and r2 to your merge relationships. MERGE (u)-[r1:POSTS]->(t);

Comment: @jose_bacoy I don't seem to see the option for adding attachments

Comment: @NathanSmith I tried doing this but I still get the same duplication as before.

Comment: @DavidAStumpf I tried doing this but it still looks like I have duplicate relationships.

Comment: To avoid duplicates every property must be the same, but I do not see any properties. When you say 2 relationships are you perhaps seeing them in separate directions? When you query make sure you specify the direction, otherwise you can get both = double counting.

Comment: @DavidAStumpf are you referring to the properties in the 2 match statements?
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///senti.csv" AS csvline
MATCH (u:User {username: csvline.username})
MATCH (t:Tweet {tweet_id: csvline.tweet_id})
MERGE (u)-[:POSTS]->(t);
MERGE (u)-[:BASED_ON]-> (l)

Answer (score 1):

You missed to find location (l) so cypher is creating dummy nodes for l and thus it is creating duplicated relationships :BASED_ON.

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///senti.csv" AS csvline
MATCH (u:User {username: csvline.username})
MATCH (t:Tweet {tweet_id: csvline.tweet_id})
MATCH (l:Location {place: csvline.location}
MERGE (u)-[:POSTS]->(t)
MERGE (u)-[:BASED_ON]-> (l)
```

Comment: Take the semicolon out of this query, and it looks correct to me.